# Using rxjs filter function to filter cloud firestore collection

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore and Angular6. I am trying to filter a collection of users based on some of their properties i.e. if they teach a subject or not.

How can I return whether the filter should be true or false? Currently, the code returns `subjectOffered` which is set to either true or false after some checks. However, in the case of what should be a match, when I console log the value, the function is returned and then the value of `subjectOffered` is set to true. Therefore, all users are filtered out. How can I return this value so the filter works correctly?

I have the following code:

```
getUserOnSearch(subject: string, level: string, oneToOne: boolean) {
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users', ref => {
        // console.log(ref);
        return ref
    });

    this.usersOnSearch = this.userCollection.valueChanges();

    return this.usersOnSearch.flatMap(user => {
        return of(user.filter(value => {
                let docID: string = value.user_subjects.id;
                let userLevelPriceDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserSubjects>;
                userLevelPriceDocument = this.afs.doc<UserSubjects>(`user_subjects/${docID}`);
                let subjectOffered: boolean = false;
                userLevelPriceDocument.valueChanges().forEach(
                    docData => {
                        let subjects: IndividualUserSubject[] = docData.subjects;
                        subjects.forEach(individualSubject => {
                            if (individualSubject.name === subject) {
                                let priceLevel: LevelPrice[] = individualSubject.prices;
                                priceLevel.forEach(indivLevel => {
                                    if (indivLevel.level == level && indivLevel.price > 0) {
                                        subjectOffered = true;
                                        console.log(subjectOffered);
                                    } else {
                                        subjectOffered = false;
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                )
                console.log(subjectOffered);
                subjectOffered;
            })
        )
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not actually returning `subjectOffered` here. It's just a statement that's doing nothing. You'll neet to return it to the `filter` function.

Comment: putting a return statement in front of subjectOffered at the end still gives me the same output.